# Batter. Cross contamination by

Tags: chips

I would like to know
Whilst cooking and serving in a fish and chip shop can i
Serve food, All dipped in same batter and rice cone containers, using
beef and chicken made sausages
Fish
Chips 
Cod roe
Burgers
Or do i need to use separate batter and rice cone containers?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure of the question here - are you asking if you can use the same containers for all the different foods you batter? If so, the answer will depend on where in the world you are.

Comment: Can you please [edit] and add some punctuation, make your question a bit more clear? I can't understand if you want to serve the food in the same containers used for dipping the batter, or if the batter and rice cone are in the same containers, and what do beef and chicken sausages have anything to do with it. Also please fix the title.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about hygiene (dont get people sick from raw meat), if you're frying it fully and making sure the meat is cooked then you should be fine to use the same batter. If you're talking about keeping allergens separate for health or religious reasons you should use separate batters.